# Rails Module not loading for presenter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Why won't my module load properly when I include it in my presenter class?

My class methods and module methods are not available when loading from rails. The module works when loading out of rails in a single file.

#### app/presenters/body_parts/method_wrapper.rb

```
module BodyParts
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.extend ClassMethods  # => Car
  end                          # => :included
  module ClassMethods

    def set_wheels(*args)
      x, *wheel_args = args                              # => [3],  [3]
      puts "Wheels class method called with: #{x.to_s}"  # => nil,  nil
      @wheels |= x                                       # => true, true
    end                                                  # => :set_wheels

    class MethodWrapper
      attr_reader :klass  # => nil

      def initialize(klass)
        @klass = klass
      end                    # => :initialize

      def wrap(method_name)
        puts "Wrapping a method"
        wrapper_callback(result)
      end                         # => :wrap
    end                           # => :wrap
  end                             # => :wrap

  private  # => BodyParts


  def wrapper_callback(result)
    "Wrapped a #{result} in the call back"
  end                                       # => :wrapper_callback

end  # => :wrapper_callback
```

#### app/presenters/car_presenter.rb

```
class CarPresenter
  include BodyParts  # => Car
  set_wheels 3       # => true

  def brand
    'Car Brand'  # => "Car Brand"
  end            # => :brand

  set_wheels 3  # => true

  def title          # policy set to 2 for title methods because of the above
    'Car Title'
  end            # => :title
end              # => :title

car_presenter = CarPresenter.new  # => #<CarPresenter:0x00fe4ed9300>
car_presenter.brand      # => "Car Brand"

# >> Wheels class method called with: 3
# >> Wheels class method called with: 3
```

#### `Binding.pry` from CarsPresenter in Rails

```
[1] pry(CarPresenter)> set_wheels 3
NameError: undefined local variable or method `set_wheels' for CarPresenter:Class
from (pry):12:in `<class:CarPresenter>'
[2] pry(CarPresenter)> BodyParts
=> BodyParts
[3] pry(CarPresenter)> self
=> CarPresenter
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way const loading works in rails, a module `BodyParts` should be defined in the top level of `presenters` directory, i.e. in `app/presenters/body_parts.rb.rb`.

Rails expects `app/presenters/body_parts/method_wrapper.rb` to define const `BodyParts::MethodWrapper`,

Read mode [in rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html).

Comment: Is there a way to keep my current directory structure without putting it directly in the presenter folder? Do you also notice that I am loading a module with class methods, instance methods and a new class?

Comment: Yup, move `MethodWrapper` to the same nesting level as `ClassMethod`

Comment: you mean as a seperate file? or just take it out of class Methods?

Comment: take it out of `ClassMethods` and keep in the same file

Comment: but then does the class become a class within an instance, not the other class?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need a class here.

Comment: I don't think there is much of a difference

Comment: Keeping my current structure, is there another way I can just reference the module to include it?

Comment: You can also put it in `app/presenters/body_parts/extension.rb` and name the module `BodyParts::Extension` and wrap the class there

Comment: What if I moved the whole BodyParts module to lib?

Comment: What I am understanding is that the module name needs the file path name, I am hoping for a simple way to over-ride that.

Comment: you can require the file manually using  `require "body_parts/method_wrapper"` on the top of `app/presenters/car_presenter.rb`